# How to resample (downsample) images while taking their actual size into account in ConTeXt?

Tags: graphics, floats, context, conversion, convert

I am currently typesetting a textbook and would like to implement a mechanism that allows me to resample images to exhibit a specific resolution, relative to their final size (mostly for the sake of exporting an interactive PDF of the document). In other words: If, e.g., an image is placed into a square of size *2"*, then, assuming a target resolution of *300ppi*, the image should be resampled to *600x600 pixels*, no matter its original size or resolution.

There seems to have been a solution using `grph-downsample` described [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Downsampling), but this method doesn't work anymore. So, I am trying to build my solution on image converters as explained [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Using_Graphics#Image_Conversion). However, this didn't work as I thought it would, as the command `gm convert` is missing a parameter (`-density` isn't doing anything on its own, it requires an additional `-resample` – but do correct me, if I'm wrong). Anyway, I came up with the following (MWE):

```
\startluacode
local function downsampler(oldname, newname, resolution)
    if not resolution or resolution == "" then
        resolution = 72
    end
    os.execute(string.format(
        'gm convert -density 300 -resample %i "%s" "%s"',
        resolution, oldname, newname)
    )
end

-- Set the PNG, TIFF and JPG converters to the above function.
figures.converters.tif.pdf = downsampler
figures.converters.jpg.pdf = downsampler
figures.converters.png.pdf = downsampler
\stopluacode

% ----------

\starttext

\section{Testing resampling of images}

\placefigure[nonumber,left][]
  {An image of size 5cm should be resampled to half the size in pixels of...}
  {\externalfigure[Cute_grey_kitten.jpg][width=5cm]}

\input{knuth}

\placefigure[nonumber,left][]
  {...an image of size 10cm.}
  {\externalfigure[Cute_grey_kitten.jpg][width=10cm]}

\input{knuth}

\stoptext
```

This looks as follows (by the way, I took the image from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cute_grey_kitten.jpg)):

[image]

The problem here is that the two figures should be resampled to **different pixel sizes**: Whereas the first occurence is only *5cm* wide, which implies an image width of **142px**, assuming *72ppi* (as in my MWE), the second one (*10cm*) needs a width of **284px** to have the same effective resolution.

So, I would need to take the *width of the figure* into account, when doing the resampling of the image in the downsampler function. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do this would be to include all of the images at full resolution, then post-process the PDF with Ghostscript. You could even run Ghostscript from "within" the ConTeXt run with [something similar to this](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2022/105929.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In case of PDF files, which are purely intended for viewing on screen, this could, indeed, be a viable solution. However, my experiences with ghostscript regarding documents intended for print production haven't been too positive, while both the PDF/X-1a and the PDF/X-4 files exported by ConTeXt are pretty good. So, I would rather not mess with the PDF files once they have been exported and was hoping to be able to resample the images before writing the PDF...